# How to write a Swift 3 loop without a mutable counter

Tags: swift

The loop decrements the loop counter if it finds an element that shouldn't be there and removes it.

```
        var iMax = numListViews
        for var i = 0; i < numListViews; i += 1 {
            if (columnsSortTypesArray[i] == "") {
                columnsSortTypesArray.removeAtIndex(i)
                i--
                iMax--
            } else {
                listViews[i].sortList(columnsSortTypesArray[i])
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is `listViews`? And `columnsSortTypesArray`, is it a `String` array? What is the `.sortList` method applied to `i`:th telement of `listView`? Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and possibly update your questions with more relevant (however non-bloated) info.

Comment: Your original code is already a bit obfuscated. Have a look at the `filter()` method!

Comment: Also, a comment as to the code above: what if `columnsSortTypesArray` has a length (num. elements) only slightly larger than `numListViews`, but contains several `""` entries? This could yield a runtime exception at the `columnsSortTypesArray[i]` (attempted) element access as `i` increases after several subsequent element removals from `columnsSortTypesArray` (after which length of `columnsSortTypesArray` could possibly be `< numListViews`).

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't have used a for loop for that purpose in the first place.
Modifying the loop variable within the loop is error-prone and a good 
example why C-style for loops have been deprecated.

To remove empty strings from an array use `filter()`:

```
columnsSortTypesArray = columnsSortTypesArray.filter { $0 != "" }
```

To populate another array based on this array, use `map()`, e.g.

```
listViews = columnsSortTypesArray.map { sortList($0) }
```

Also: If you have two (or more) arrays which always have to be kept
in sync, consider to define a `struct WhatEver` with two (or more) properties
and use a single array of these `WhatEver` elements instead.